# jQuery cycle plugin working on one page but not another

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm using the jQuery cycle plugin in a custom Wordpress widget and it works fine on the homepage, but when I try and use the widget again on an interior page it doesn't seem to play ball

(Working on the homepage)

http://www.vof-redesign.com.php5-11.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com

(Not working on interior page)

http://www.vof-redesign.com.php5-11.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/about/

It's the exact same widget on both pages, does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the about page (wrap the image with the div below )

```
<div id="slideshow" style="height: 420px; overflow: hidden;" >
<img width="1135px" height="206px" src="http://www.vof-redesign.com.php5-11.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/wp-content/themes/vidalia-onion-festival/images/page-banner.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: That worked a treat. So does that mean for the widget slideshow to appear, the #slideshow one needs to be on the same page?

Comment: Yes you must always add the selector ...  plz accept my question if that helped you

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I've spent a good 3 hours trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Javascript error on the second page. That means you need to check the following:

1. The JS includes to make sure every dependency is loading.
2. The markup that you are feeding the cycle plugin.
3. The way you are calling the cycle plugin on the second page (might be different from the first page).

The complaint I saw from Chrome was in the plugin, so chances are something you are doing on `/about` is making it unhappy.

Comment: This error comes up on firebug.
.
.
next is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

if (opts.slideResize && w !== false && next.cycleW > 0)

Comment: I got the same error, but I'm not doing anything different on interior pages than I am on the homepage. All JS is loaded from either the header or footer which is used on all pages. The widget markup is identical on the homepage as on interior pages too :/